# What is the shorcut key to open emoji picker on vs code on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

Keyboard shortcuts ***ctrl + .*** for opening emoji picker is not working inside **VSCode**. However the same key combination do works in **gedit**. I have tried google search suggestion ***ctrl + alt + i*** in ***VSCode***, which is also not working.

Comment: Are you using the [emojisense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.emojisense). I don't believe this is native VS Code behaviour.

Comment: No I am not using emojisense extension. But the same key combination works absolutely fine in Windows.

Comment: For me, on Windows the combination ctrl+alt+i adds a `í` (looks like a regular `i` but with an accent) and I can't find anything in command palette related to emoji

Answer (score 1):

You can install emote app on ubuntu. Use Ctrl + Alt + E to open or configure shortcut in settings>keyboard>view and customize shortcuts>custom shortcuts>then add a shortcut

```
sudo snap install emote
```